# mounting webdav folder a non sudoer user fails

Tags: mount, webdav, davfs2

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.
I need to mount a webdav directory, and it is critical non sudoers may access it.

I followed these instructions:
http://techiech.blogspot.de/2013/04/mounting-webdav-directory-in-linux.html

Mounting the directory with sudo now works, but credentials are being asked.

Mounting as non suoders results in :

```
/sbin/mount.davfs:/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf:35: user option in system configuration file
/sbin/mount.davfs:/home/<username>/.davfs2/davfs2.conf:24: system option in user configuration file
```

and apparently nothing happens, and I need to hit ctrl+c to get the prompt again.

The lines pointed at in davfs2.conf correspond to uncommented lines:

```
ignore_home       kernoops,distccd
secrets         ~/.davfs2/secrets
```

Any idea what may be wrong ?

Comment: What's the output of `ll ~/.davfs2/secrets`? Also, are you sure you added the user to the `davfs` group?

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount it within `/etc/fstab`
you must be installed **davfs2**

paste this line to /etc/fstab

```
https://somedomain.xyz/webdav.php/somefolder/ /mnt/s02 davfs,_netdev defaults 0 0
```

then

```
mount -a
```